# return values from calling a function using lua alchemy

Tags: actionscript-3, lua, alchemy, alchemyapi

Im calling a function in lua from actionscript using
 `callstack : Array = luaAlchemyInstance.doString("luafunction");`

my function should return some values

```
function luafunction()
return true, 125
end
```

When i look at the callstack array returned by the function in as3, I recieve only the success/ fail part.  The array length is 1, true, and contains none of my return values.

Any idea whats going wrong?  Cheers

Comment: I don't know lua-alchemy, but shouldn't it be luaAlchemyInstance.doString("return luafunction()")? Notice the return and the call parentheses.

Comment: @MiKy: you should post that as an answer, so we can give you proper recognition!

Comment: Hey, a first question about lua-alchemy on SO! Cool! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doString()` returns array of the values, returned by a call. First item of that array is `true` or `false`, indicating call success or failure. If it is `false`, second item is the error message.

Also note that `doString()` takes actual Lua code as an argument, so it should be

```
doString("return luafunction()")
```

See [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/lua-alchemy/wiki/As3ToLuaInterface) and [example](https://github.com/lua-alchemy/lua-alchemy/blob/master/demo/LuaAlchemyDemo/src/LuaView.mxml#L66-72).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know lua-alchemy, but if `doString()` follows the same semantics as in standard Lua, the proper way to call the function should be:

```
callstack : Array = luaAlchemyInstance.doString("return luafunction()");
```

Answer (score -2):

I've only ever seen functions in Actionscript that return a single variable type at a time (Number, String, Boolean, etc).

It looks like you are trying to return a Boolean and a Number/int/uint value at the same time.

You *could* just try to return both as object values, something like this:

```
function luafunction():Object
{
var obj:Object = new Object();
obj.myBoolean = true;
obj.myNumber = 125;
return obj;
}
```

Then you can retrieve your values by something like:

```
trace(obj.myBoolean, obj.myNumber);
```

Comment: Sorry, but the question is about calling Lua functions with lua-alchemy, not just returning several values from arbitrary AS3 code.